# Weird issue with element data attribute in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a very weird issue in my case

I want to detect the total number of the clicked box

I have my codes like the following

I have 100 `divs` that has class name as `.unit`.

```
$('.unit).click(function(){
    $(this).attr('data-boxcolor','green')
})

//submit button
$('#submit-btn').click(function(){
        checkAnswer()
 })

//remove all the attribute and start over
 $('#clear-btn').click(function(){
      $('.unit').removeAttr('data-boxcolor')
 })


function checkAnswer(){
        var greenCount=0
        var colorLimit=4;

    $('.unit').each(function(){
    var t = $(this).data('boxcolor')

    switch(t){
    case 'green':
                greenCount++;                 
    break;
    ….MORE...   
     default:
    }

    if(greenCount > colorLimit){
        alert('too many boxes)
    }
  }
```

When I first select more than 4 boxes, it pops the alert box which is correct. however, after I hit the `clear-btn` then even only select 1 box, the '`too many boxes`' alert still show. I check the clicked box based on the data attribute and I am not sure why this is happening. Can someone please help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `$('.unit)` and `alert('too many boxes)` are missing a closing `'`. Is this a typo in your question, or in your original source code?

Comment: and a small point ... use `.removeData('boxcolor')` instead of `removeAttr('data-boxcolor')`. also, `$(this).data({boxcolor:'green'})` instead of `$(this).attr('data-boxcolor','green')`.